# Chitubox: Is it possible to place a hollow object flat on the build plate and use internal supports?

Tags: slicing, resin, support-structures, elegoo-saturn, chitubox

I have a bust that I want to print flat on the build plate of an Elegoo resin printer, but I want to place supports inside it without having to add a skate or raft?

Is this possible, and if so how